# Linkedin api is responding with SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)

Tags: linkedin-api

When requesting posts data using LinkedIn API - The response is SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired). Is there an issue with the API at the moment?

Comment: are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn provide a [status page](https://linkedin.statuspage.io/) for their APIs, best to check there. Currently there are no reported issues.

To enable the community to help you I feel you should provide more details, what API specifically are you using, what endpoint are you calling, etc.